# Can source code files with different encoding coexist in (the same) Java (project in Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I know Java uses [UTF-16 internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16) and expects [`.properties` files to be in ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) by default.

I'm currently working on a project that was written in Eclipse, whose default encoding on our systems is cp-1252. I'm thinking utf-8 would be a much more sensible option, going forward.

However, given the scale of the project (it's split up into modules and uses libraries from all over the place), I can't just batch-convert all source code files in one go.

Will Java have a problem with some files in a project being in one encoding and some in another? (Clearly, having entire libraries written in encodings that are different from one another doesn't seem to be a problem - probably because they are all UTF-16 once compiled, anyway.)

Would Eclipse be able to handle that (i.e. different encodings per file) correctly?

Comment: I never had a problem with different encodings in different files, but I was far from having your size of project.

Comment: Will Java compile just fine, or will I have to specify command line options, in your experience?

Comment: Everything was fine as-is using eclipse. The case I dealt with was one file with Chinese and Hebrew characters which eclipse had to save in UTF (don't remember 8 or 16), and the other files were in the default encoding. If you have something more complicated then I don't know what could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You can choose the default encoding to use for the whole Eclipse project:

- right click on a project
- `resource` part
- `Text file encoding` zone, check `Other` and choose `UTF-8` (or what you want) in the combo

You can also change the encoding for a particular file:

- right click on the file
- `resource` part
- `Text file encoding` zone, check `Other` and choose `UTF-8` (or what you want) in the combo

Preferences are store in the hidden folder `.settings` in your project. File encoding preferences are store in the `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`.

Thoses preferences can be commited using your favorite source control and shared with other developpers.