# How to determine whether utf-8 or cp1252 encoding?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

Is there way in perl to determine which of `utf-8` or `cp1252` the encoding of a string is?

Comment: If you have at least a few bytes in the range 0x80-0xFF, they would quickly produce invalid UTF-8 if they are in CP1252. See the proposed duplicate for how to detect that.

Comment: I have filenames that people are creating from Windows or Mac, which means it is either `cp1252` or `utf8` and I need a way to automatically determine which it is.

Comment: Let me put it this way: UTF-8 is *extremely* picky about what constititutes a valid sequence. Every random string is valid cp1252 but very few random strings are valid UTF-8. Of course, if the file name doesn't contain any characters in the range 0x80-0xFF, it is valid UTF-8 *and* CP1252, and semantically identical in both scenarios.

Comment: Of course, the real way is to have the person giving it to you not leave out that essential information.

Comment: I don't see that this is really a duplicate (of what was marked); while that is a useful page it's just one way to go at this. I've added a link from ikegami's answer. Finding more would be helpful.

Comment: There are three to five possible results for this analysis (depending if you consider Windows-1252 to have 256 codepoints or fewer (248, 251)): valid and the same text in both; valid in both but different text; valid in UTF-8 but not in Windows-1252; valid in Windows-1252 but not in UTF-8; invalid in both. [That's the general idea for any two candidate encodings; perhaps valid in UTF-8 but not in Windows-1252 isn't actually possible.] And, then, after considering validity, you can get into likelihood (informed guessing), if you know something about the text expected.

Answer (score 1):

The core [Encode::Guess](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Guess.html) should be up to task for this<sup>†</sup>

```
use Encode::Guess;

my $enc = guess_encoding($data, qw(cp1252));  # utf8 among defaults
```

and then

> ```
> ref($enc) or die "Can't guess: $enc"; # trap error this way
> $utf8 = $enc->decode($data);
> ```

(from docs).

In order to *not* also use the default "*ascii, utf8 and UTF-16/32 with BOM*" change that first

```
Encode::Guess->set_suspects(qw(utf8 cp1252));
```

and then get the encoding

```
my $enc = guess_encoding($data);
```

Or, copied from docs

> ```
> my $decoder = Encode::Guess->guess($data);
> die $decoder unless ref($decoder);
> my $utf8 = $decoder->decode($data);
> ```

See documentation for details.

---

<sup>†</sup> There are plenty of differences; see comment by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) and for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324622/what-characters-do-not-directly-map-from-cp1252-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $could_be_utf8 = utf8::decode( my $tmp = $string );

my $could_be_cp1252 = $string !~ /[\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D]/;
```

If you need to handle a string that contains a mix of both, see [Fixing a file consisting of both UTF-8 and Windows-1252](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28681864/589924).