# Error when compiling: unmappable character (0x90D) for encoding windows-1252

Tags: java

I get compile error when typing `javac Main.java` in terminal and the message i get is:

```
.\Constants.java:32: error: unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding windows-1252.
```

I know it caused by this bit of code:

```
public static final String[] UNICODE_TEXT = {
      "― ", // CELL_EMPTY
      "✗ ", // CELL_X
      " ", // CELL_O
      "  ", // CELL_INVALID
  };
```

It is the `"✗ "` and the `" "` that causes this problem since they are special characters. I don't want to change the code since it was provided by the course. How can I compile this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unmappable character for encoding" warning in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464874/unmappable-character-for-encoding-warning-in-java). Adding `-encoding UTF-8` to your javac command ought to fix it

Comment: I tried using javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 file_name.java. the compile did work however other normal characters were wrongly encoded

Comment: @Muja If you plan to use "ISO-8859-1" as the argument for the `-encoding` parameter, you have to save the source file in that format (and not ins "windows-1252").

Comment: Don’t use ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252.  Your file is a UTF-8 file.  “” is [U+1D442 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL O](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d442/index.htm).  In UTF-8, its bytes are: 0xf0 0x9d 0x91 0x82.  That is where the 0x9D comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Do set your Java Encoding correctly by creating the environment variable called `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and set it to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399955/9758687